# Is there any reason to prefer dict() to {} in Python?

Tags: python, idioms

Is there any reason to prefer `dict()` to `{}` when initialising an empty dictionary in Python?

Comment: nah it's whatever

Comment: Using literals is faster, but as far as readability is concerned, it's a matter of opinion

Comment: if you want to treat keys as symbols/atoms at writetime, yes `dict()` is preferable. `dict(a='foo', b='loo')` -))